# Regex to match any domain except two domains

Tags: regex

in my htaccess i'm trying to set document root for all park domains to a specific path except two main domains, so basically i need a regex to match any domain except tow domains
i found something like this

```
^(?!foo$|bar$).*
```

and this

```
(?>[\w-]+)(?<!tea|nuka-cola)
```

but can not get it work with my situation because there is a **dot tld** in domain name and i want to use regex there too
here is my current regex

```
^(.*?)\.(com|net)$
```

instead of (.*?) i want to make exception there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative look behind:

```
^(.*?)(?<!(foo)|(bar))\.(com|net)$
```

Not sure what you want, but this regex will not match urls ending in `foo.com` or `bar.net` etc

Comment: i tested this code here http://www.rubular.com/ and it says: Invalid pattern in look-behind.

Comment: `^(.*?)(?<!foo|bar)\.(com|net)$` <- try this

Comment: I just tested this regex on numerous sites and it's fine. I got it to work on rubular by spotting the OR, to this: `^(.*?)(?<!foo)(?<!bar)\.(com|net)$`. My guess is that ruby has a limited look around engine that doesn't allow OR logic